# PLSQL : ORA-00904 invalid identifier in Cursor Select

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql, database-cursor

I have `EXTERNAL TABLE` created as below.

```
CREATE TABLE EXTERNAL_TABLE
( "col1"           DATE
, "col2"           DATE
) ORGANIZATION external
  ( TYPE oracle_loader
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY  INPUT_DIRECTORY
    ACCESS  PARAMETERS
    ( RECORDS DELIMITED  BY NEWLINE
      LOGFILE 'Some.log'
      BADFILE 'Some.bad'
      FIELDS  TERMINATED BY "|" LDRTRIM
      ( "col1" DATE
      , "col2" DATE MASK "MM/DD/YYYY"
      )
    )
    LOCATION ('SomeDat.dat')
  )
  PARALLEL 1
  REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
/
```

I am populating the data loaded into external table into a transaction table for further processing.

```
PROCEDURE upload
IS
lv_post_dt DATE;
TYPE dataTblType IS TABLE OF My_Transaction_Table%ROWTYPE;
lv_dataTbl    dataTblType;
    
CURSOR externalCur IS
      SELECT lv_post_dt col1,
             col2  --ORA-00904 invalid identifier is encountered here
      FROM  EXTERNAL_TABLE;
      
BEGIN
lv_post_dt := SYSTIMESTAMP;

OPEN externalCur;
    LOOP
      FETCH externalCur BULK COLLECT
        INTO lv_dataTbl LIMIT 25000;
    
      EXIT WHEN lv_dataTbl.COUNT = 0;
    
      FOR i IN 1 .. lv_dataTbl.COUNT LOOP
        --Insert recordsinto My_Transaction_Table
      END LOOP;
CLOSE externalCur;

END upload;
```

I tried below as well.

```
CURSOR externalCur IS
      SELECT lv_post_dt col1,
             ext.col2  --ORA-00904 invalid identifier is encountered here
      FROM  EXTERNAL_TABLE ext;
  
CURSOR externalCur IS
      SELECT lv_post_dt col1,
             EXTERNAL_TABLE.col2  --ORA-00904 invalid identifier is encountered here
      FROM  EXTERNAL_TABLE;
```

Even though `col2` belongs to `EXTERNAL_TABLE`, why I am getting invalid identifier error and how to fix this?

When I write `lv_post_dt col1` then why it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of *unfortunate* double quotes. Why did you use them? They bring nothing but problems.

This is what you did (disregard the fact that this isn't an external table):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE EXTERNAL_TABLE
  2  ( "col1"           DATE
  3  , "col2"           DATE
  4  );

Table created.
```

Can you select *everything* from it? Sure:

```
SQL> select * from external_table;

no rows selected
```

Can you select only `col2`? Not really; here's your `ORA-00904: invalid identifier`:

```
SQL> select col2 from external_table;
select col2 from external_table
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "COL2": invalid identifier
```

Why is that so? Because of **double quotes**. Once you use them and have mixed (or lower) letter case while naming objects, you have to use double quotes and match letter case every time:

```
SQL> select "col2" from external_table;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

What should you do? In my opinion, drop the table and recreate it, but this time omit double quotes, everywhere.